# Unable to change column position dynamically (Datagrid Rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid

I am trying to generate the columns of my table with data coming from a table that stores the order of each column that was created when the user rearrange the columns.

E.g in my property_grid.rb file I am trying to generate the columns using this array `["Attribute 1", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 3"]`.

```
["Attribute 1", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 3"].each do |v|
  case v
   when 'Attribute 1'
    column(:attribute_1)
   when 'Attribute 2'
    column(:attribute_2)
   when 'Attribute 3'
    column(:attribute_3)
  end
end
```

This works great the first time I reload the page but when the attribute array becomes `["Attribute 3", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 1"]` it doesn't change.

If I add a comment or anything else to the property_grid.rb file then it seems to work. I don't understand why it only works if I manually add something to this file. Any idea why this is happening and how can I dynamically change the position of these columns?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `map` instead of `each` method. `each` method returns the initial array, `map` return the result of the block

Comment: I tried map. Still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` to indicate the position of a column. See example:

```rb
column(:activated, :header => "Active", :order => "activated", :after => :name) do
  self.activated?
end
```

Example from: https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/blob/master/Readme.markdown#columns